# Doing a loop inside a tidyverse pipeline but keeping it 1 to 1?

Tags: r, loops, regression

Im currently trying to do a loop on a tidyverse pipe I wrote, however id like to do it in a way thats like a nested loop but is 1-1. Say I have i and j, I would like for when i = 1 or first element in a column list, then j is also 1 on the first element in a column list.

I have code looking like this, (ARPU = Ad revenue per user)

```
Dftest <- df %>% mutate(Numerator = `Day 7 ARPU` * `Installs`)
%>% group_by(platform, source) 
%>% summarise(WeightedMean = sum(Numerator)/sum(installs)) 
%>% mutate(Day = "7")
```

I have alot of columns of Day X ARPU where x ranges from 7, 14, ...,180 etc. Id like to make it so that when I run say Day 30 ARPU in the numerator, id like to pair it with a column labeled "Day". In this case since I used Day 30 ARPU, the "Day" column would indicate 30.

Is there a way to accomplish this with loops? where I can make a list like c(Day 7 ARPU, Day 14 ARPU, ...DAY 180 ARPU) and a Day List like c(7, 14,..., 180)?

I want the loop to make it look like this with i and j matching (no when i = day 180, j should be 180 and not 7)

```
Dftest <- df %>% mutate(Numerator = i * `Installs`) 
%>% group_by(platform, source) 
%>% summarise(WeightedMean = sum(Numerator)/sum(installs)) 
%>% mutate(Day = j)
```

i in c(Day 7 ARPU, Day 14 ARPU, ...DAY 180 ARPU)

j in c(7, 14,..., 180)?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without a reproducible example or copy-paste data but this should do the trick. No loops necessary if we just pivot_longer first.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Day"), names_to = "Dayname", values_to = "ARPU") %>%
  mutate(Numerator = ARPU * Installs) %>%
  group_by(Dayname, platform, source) %>%
  summarise(WeightedMean = sum(Numerator)/sum(Installs))  %>%
  mutate(day=str_extract(Dayname, pattern = "(?<=Day )\\d+"))
```